# How to check UFW status without sudo (or being root)?

Tags: sudo, firewall, ufw

I'm running some scripts to check the UFW status and would like to run `sudo ufw status` without having to do `sudo`. I was hoping to find a *firewall* or *ufw* group to add myself to, but I didn't find any.

How can I allow any user X to do the `ufw status` without being root or asking for *sudo* password?

---

**UPDATE**:

I wanted to try to add my own file to `/etc/sudoers.d/`, but was lazy so decided to copy one already existing, like this:

```bsh
sudo cp /etc/sudoers.d/mintupdate /etc/sudoers.d/firewall_status
```

**Don't do That!** You will not be able to do sudo or login again. I had to do a boot recovery. Instead use:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/ufwstatus
```

Now just follow the accepted answer below.

Comment: Would it be an option to run `sudo ufw ...` without password? I doubt that running firewall things without root privilege will work.

Comment: No, that would open a huge security hole.

Comment: What would be the difference between to allow a group using ufw without and with sudo?

Comment: Well it depend on what you mean. If you mean to just `chmod 777`, then I'd rather say no, as any user could disable the FW. I'm looking for a proper solution to add people to groups or add specific users/execs to some sudoers list.

Comment: One doesn't need `sudo` - simply `service ufw status`

Comment: @waltinator that only tells you the service status; `ufw status` lists the ruleset

Comment: I've linked to a similar question - but I have to point out the obvious:  If the user whom you don't trust with sudo privileges has the ability to run `ufw`, they also have the ability to turn off the firewall.

Comment: Also, please make a direct note of the use of the command `visudo` for editing the sudoers files....

Comment: @not2qubit: I did not mean to change access rights in the filesystem with `chmod` but rather run `sudo ufw ...` without providing a password. You could lock down that to a group or user as linked by Charles Green.

Comment: I have now edited `/etc/sudoers` with `Cmnd_Alias FWSTAT = /usr/sbin/ufw` and `xxxx ALL=NOPASSWD: FWSTAT`. But I'm still asked to provide password...

Comment: Do I also need to reload something after having edited sudoers?

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @vidarlo Definitely not an XY problem, but thanks for the link so that I can use that  myself when I come across questions like it.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yep, that dup link was really helpful but did not completely resolve my problem. However, I marked it as solved too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an `/etc/sudoers.d/` file that works for me:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/ufwstatus
Cmnd_Alias      UFWSTATUS = /usr/sbin/ufw status

%ufwstatus      ALL=NOPASSWD: UFWSTATUS
```

Then add the new "ufwstatus" group (here added as a *system* group):

```
sudo groupadd -r ufwstatus
```

Your otherwise non-privileged user must be added to the `ufwstatus` group e.g.

```
sudo gpasswd --add testuser ufwstatus
```

In order for the change to take effect, the user needs to log in again:

```
su - testuser
```

Then

```
testuser@xenial-vm:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
3389/tcp                   ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
111                        ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
```

but other `ufw` commands are disallowed (even slight variants, such as `status --verbose`):

```
testuser@xenial-vm:~$ sudo ufw status --verbose
Sorry, user testuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/ufw status --verbose' as root on xenial-vm.

testuser@xenial-vm:~$ sudo ufw disable
Sorry, user testuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/ufw disable' as root on xenial-vm.
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. This solved my problem
with the small differences that: (1) `su - testuser` didn't work, so I needed to reboot in order for the new group and *sudoers* policy to take place. (2) Funny and contrary to logic, `sudo ufw enable/disable` and `sudo ufw status verbose` now also works without password.

Comment: Nice answer - and avoids the "too much permission" problem!

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks - although I'm concerned by the OP's comment above asserting that it **does** allow passwordless ufw enable/disable: I don't believe it should

Comment: I hadn't noticed that - I would have to try this in my VM

Comment: BTW. I am running this on `Mint 19.1 (Xfce)`, if that matters.